# Referencing a Compiled Business Layer in a DotNetNuke Module

Tags: deployment, assemblies, reference, dotnetnuke

I was wondering if it is possible to create a DNN module that references a compiled business layer, instead of using just the data provider approach that's included in the default project. How would such a project be deployed? Just copy the compiled assembly that I'm referencing into the website bin folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can reference assemblies in the bin from your module's project.